# Aggregate rows in a DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, aggregate-functions

I have a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this

```
ProductId CountThisWeek   CountLastWeek
        1          10.0            15.0         
        1          20.0             5.0

        2           5.0            10.0
        2        DBNull            15.0
        2          10.0          DBNull

        3        DBNull            15.0
        3        DBNull            15.0
```

I need to obtain a new DataTable (or, if not, at least a anonymous data structure, like a dictionary) by "compressing" (sum by productId) my initial DataTable, like this :

```
ProductId CountThisWeek   CountLastWeek
        1          30.0            20.0         
        2          15.0            25.0
        3        DBNull            30.0
```

The rule is simple: DBNull + Value = Value, DBNull + DBNull = DBNull

I try to implement this aggregation, like this:

```
(from row in table.AsEnumerable()
group row by row.Field<int>("ProductId") into g
select g).ToDictionary(
g => g.Key, 
g => new {
   CountThisWeek = g.Sum(r => row.Field<decimal>("CountThisWeek")),
   CountLastWeek = g.Sum(r => row.Field<decimal>("CountLastWeek"))
}
```

but this Sum does not take into consideration my DBNull rule...

I can't do it with nullable decimal?

```
g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal?>("CountThisWeek")),
```

So, perhaps I need to do something like

```
g.Aggregate((summRow, nextRow) => {
                        DataRow dr = summRow.Table.NewRow();
                        decimal? sum = summRow.Field<decimal?>("CountThisWeek");
                        decimal? next = nextRow.Field<decimal?>("CountThisWeek");
                        decimal? result = (!sum.HasValue && !next.HasValue) ? 
                            (decimal?)null : sum ?? 0 + next ?? 0;
                        dr["CountThisWeek"] = result;
                        return dr;
                    }),
```

is it the best way to achieve what I trying?

And I would like to obtain `decimal?` instead of `DataRow` in the aggregate function...

Comment: are you try `g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("CountThisWeek")??0)`?

Comment: no, DbNull+DbNull should be "null", not "0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`Aggregate` function with Accumulator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx) like this

```
g.Aggregate((decimal?)null,(summRow, nextRow) => 
                    nextRow.IsNull("CountThisWeek")?
                        summRow:
                        ((summRow??0) + nextRow.Field<decimal>("CountThisWeek"))
                ),
```

Comment: As I understand the Aggregate "performs" better than Sum. ... Good fix from `<decimal?>` => `<decimal>`... By the way, in my case it returns InvalidCastException in case of "decimal", and a correct value in case of "double"...

Comment: possibly because your field is double instead of decimal?

Comment: @serhio, regarding performance, it depends on the data set on which the function will be executed, `Aggregate` in all cases loop on all collection once, in sample @BobVale possibly min operations count is collection.lenght if all is null, and max - collection.lenght*2

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
(from row in table.AsEnumerable()
group r by r.Field<int>("ProductId") into g
select g).ToDictionary(
g => g.Key, 
g => new {
   CountThisWeek = g.All(r => r.IsNull("CountThisWeek")) ?
                      null : 
                      (decimal?)g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("CountThisWeek")),
   CountLastWeek = g.All(r => r.IsNull("CountLastWeek")) ? 
                       null : 
                       (decimal?)g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("CountLastWeek"))
}
```

Comment: You have exactly 10,000 rep and I can't stand it, have a vote.